# How to download from Azure blob storage using connection string and stored URL

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, .net-5

I am trying to update my nuget packages for a .net-core project as part of upgradation into .NET5.0. At the moment, to upload/download blobs to Azure Blob Storage we are using the package **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob** version 11.1.6. Since this package has been deprecated, I am trying to replace its usage with **Azure.Storage.Blobs**.

With the earlier implementation, we were able to download data using a **CloudBlockBlob** which was initialized by passing the URL of the blob and a **CloudBlobClient**. Here is something similar to our current implementation:

```
public async Task<byte[]> DownloadBlobAsByteArrayDataAsync(string connectionString, string url)
{
    Uri blobUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

    var azureCloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);           
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = azureCloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  
    var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobUri, cloudBlobClient );

    if (!await cloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync())
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"No data found at: [{url}]");

    byte[] bytes;
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memStream);
        bytes = memStream.ToArray();
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

I was able to make the necessary modification to get the upload to storage working using **BlobClient**, **BlobContainerClient** and **BlobServiceClient**.

But, I cannot seem to find any document on how download can be implemented with the latest package.

Comment: I answered similar question yesterday and that's why I closed yours as a duplicate of that. Please see if the solution I proposed there works for you or not. If not, I will reopen this question.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually with the v11 sdk, all I had to do was initialize a BlobServiceClient using a connection string and upload/download using this. Now it seems that downloading using the connection string requires me to update my Key Vaults to not use conn string anymore, instead set up account name and account key. 

I was more interested in knowing whether I can achieve both upload/download without me having to tear up too much.

Comment: Plus the documents for v12 sdk is really poor

Comment: I found out what I was looking for here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12414